Excel SPILL error, automatically adding rows?
In Sheet1 I have column B and C as the keys and then 19 columns with different data for each of those keys.
In Sheet2 I need to get the top 5 values (including also ties) with their keys for each of those 19 columns.
I'm on Excel 365 and I've managed to do it with FILTER function, but what if I want records to be shown only if average > 50?
It seems I still need to leave rows for that FILTER function to operate in case average it's > 50, for avoiding SPILL error...
Is there a way for avoiding those empty rows?
I mean, this is what I'd like to have

so to have average data one close to another, but in this way I'll face SPILL error if average is > 50.
Being 19 blocks (% somma1, % somma2,...) it won't be too compact if leaving 5 (better, 6 for considering ties) empty rows for each of them...
It would be great if there was a way for automatically adding the needed rows when the FILTER function returns something cause average is > 50.
Or should I do something different?
EDIT:
Here's the formula in Sheet2!A2:
=SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!B2:D104859;1;2;COLUMN(Sheet1!$D$2)-COLUMN(Sheet1!$B$2)+1);Sheet1!D2:D104859>=LARGE(Sheet1!D:D;5));3;-1)
The best thing would be to have all those blocks (Sheet2!A1:C6) 'closed' if C1<50, and 'opened' if C1>=50
Here's a markdown of Sheet1:


| date     | key1    | key2    | % data1 | % data2 | % data3 | % data4 | % data5 | % data6 | % data7 | % data8 | % data9 | % data10 | % data11 | % data12 | % data13 | % data14 | % data15 | % data16 | % data17 | % data19 | % data19 |
| -------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 01/04/24 | key1 1  | key2 1  | 17,06   | 23,858  | 22,244  | 15,554  | 21,514  | 47,017  | 52,983  | 30,739  | 46,189  | 47,91    | 52,09    | 24,042   | 40,407   | 16,364   | 13,641   | 52,919   | 47,081   | 14,002   | 67,286   |
| 02/04/24 | key1 2  | key2 2  | 12,087  | 20,004  | 22,071  | 18,264  | 21,13   | 35,742  | 64,258  | 42,187  | 55,646  | 46,58    | 53,42    | 24,804   | 43,066   | 18,261   | 23,314   | 52,526   | 47,474   | 28,792   | 59,752   |
| 03/04/24 | key1 3  | key2 3  | 19,584  | 25,235  | 21,678  | 13,967  | 25,306  | 52,419  | 47,581  | 25,903  | 48,001  | 49,017   | 50,983   | 27,034   | 61,294   | 34,26    | 39,219   | 50,303   | 49,697   | 61,672   | 41,138   |
| 04/04/24 | key1 4  | key2 4  | 23,788  | 26,695  | 19,972  | 11,207  | 24,202  | 61,081  | 38,919  | 18,946  | 35,562  | 49,47    | 50,53    | 11,734   | 14,92    | 3,186    | 7,517    | 62,807   | 37,193   | 35,347   | 19,46    |
| 05/04/24 | key1 5  | key2 5  | 5,871   | 26,978  | 18,024  | 19,339  | 7,178   | 19,837  | 80,163  | 62,14   | 31,747  | 36,039   | 63,961   | 27,025   | 57,254   | 30,229   | 7,523    | 50,01    | 49,99    | 79,902   | 4,411    |
| 06/04/24 | key1 6  | key2 6  | 12,215  | 20,123  | 22,101  | 18,205  | 21,803  | 36,045  | 63,955  | 41,854  | 56,702  | 46,821   | 53,179   | 25,365   | 45,306   | 19,941   | 25,659   | 52,176   | 47,824   | 31,629   | 59,32    |
| 07/04/24 | key1 7  | key2 7  | 12,175  | 20,086  | 22,092  | 18,224  | 22,279  | 35,95   | 64,05   | 41,958  | 57,678  | 46,953   | 53,047   | 25,719   | 46,9     | 21,181   | 28,276   | 51,968   | 48,032   | 56,342   | 36,863   |
| 08/04/24 | key1 8  | key2 8  | 36,403  | 20,972  | 8,055   | 2,32    | 42,708  | 88,968  | 11,032  | 2,977   | 18,72   | 54,963   | 45,037   | 8,665    | 10,489   | 1,823    | 5,029    | 66,731   | 33,269   | 30,541   | 15,468   |
| 09/04/24 | key1 9  | key2 9  | 25,49   | 26,978  | 19,036  | 10,074  | 29,637  | 64,509  | 35,491  | 16,455  | 41,444  | 50,253   | 49,747   | 15,064   | 20,279   | 5,215    | 9,49     | 59,458   | 40,542   | 43,913   | 18,916   |
| 10/04/24 | key1 10 | key2 10 | 19,006  | 24,953  | 21,84   | 14,337  | 18,221  | 51,198  | 48,802  | 26,961  | 34,323  | 47,74    | 52,26    | 17,636   | 24,938   | 7,302    | 11,525   | 57,315   | 42,685   | 19,747   | 49,174   |
| 11/04/24 | key1 11 | key2 11 | 14,974  | 22,432  | 22,404  | 16,782  | 19,85   | 42,403  | 57,597  | 35,192  | 47,243  | 47,056   | 52,944   | 26,972   | 56,159   | 29,187   | 23,772   | 50,473   | 49,527   | 73,907   | 18,874   |
| 12/04/24 | key1 12 | key2 12 | 10,001  | 17,887  | 21,327  | 19,072  | 17,879  | 30,683  | 69,317  | 47,99   | 52,838  | 44,656   | 55,344   | 26,092   | 48,821   | 22,729   | 26,175   | 51,623   | 48,377   | 28,263   | 64,212   |
| 13/04/24 | key1 13 | key2 13 | 6,514   | 13,534  | 18,749  | 19,479  | 20,002  | 21,615  | 78,385  | 59,636  | 61,528  | 43,269   | 56,731   | 23,933   | 76,651   | 52,718   | 52,47    | 48,608   | 51,392   | 46,525   | 61,843   |
| 14/04/24 | key1 14 | key2 14 | 22,456  | 26,347  | 20,609  | 12,09   | 28,024  | 58,372  | 41,628  | 21,019  | 46,25   | 49,739   | 50,261   | 9,068    | 11,046   | 1,978    | 6,025    | 66,157   | 33,843   | 25,369   | 22,385   |
| 15/04/24 | key1 15 | key2 15 | 6,437   | 13,425  | 18,667  | 19,467  | 17,991  | 21,405  | 78,595  | 59,927  | 57,996  | 42,296   | 57,704   | 22,612   | 36,153   | 13,542   | 19,949   | 53,904   | 46,096   | 29,534   | 53,337   |
| 16/04/24 | key1 16 | key2 16 | 34,42   | 22,226  | 22,402  | 16,935  | 14,822  | 41,788  | 58,212  | 35,81   | 35,925  | 45,741   | 54,259   | 22,097   | 34,784   | 12,687   | 12,905   | 54,18    | 45,82    | 15,556   | 61,939   |
| 17/04/24 | key1 17 | key2 17 | 13,307  | 21,098  | 22,299  | 17,677  | 21,363  | 38,602  | 61,398  | 39,099  | 53,772  | 47,005   | 52,995   | 25,367   | 45,312   | 19,945   | 21,701   | 52,108   | 47,892   | 23,232   | 65,223   |
| 18/04/24 | key1 18 | key2 18 | 15,737  | 22,985  | 22,381  | 16,344  | 24,658  | 44,109  | 55,891  | 33,51   | 55,158  | 48,348   | 51,652   | 19,357   | 28,403   | 9,046    | 15,425   | 56,053   | 43,947   | 27,455   | 47,092   |
| 19/04/24 | key1 19 | key2 19 | 19,405  | 25,15   | 21,731  | 14,082  | 22,031  | 52,041  | 47,959  | 26,229  | 41,897  | 48,45    | 51,55    | 26,449   | 51,023   | 24,574   | 30,225   | 51,391   | 48,609   | 60,866   | 34,793   |
| 20/04/24 | key1 20 | key2 20 | 26,181  | 27,039  | 18,616  | 9,613   | 29,702  | 65,896  | 34,104  | 15,488  | 39,697  | 50,347   | 49,653   | 14,299   | 18,988   | 4,689    | 10,356   | 60,165   | 39,835   | 36,72    | 25,292   |
| 21/04/24 | key1 21 | key2 21 | 30,5    | 26,583  | 15,445  | 6,731   | 29,586  | 74,58   | 25,42   | 9,974   | 26,472  | 51,153   | 48,847   | 21,822   | 34,08    | 12,258   | 13,047   | 54,361   | 45,639   | 60,943   | 16,174   |
| 22/04/24 | key1 22 | key2 22 | 13,685  | 21,416  | 22,343  | 17,482  | 11,226  | 39,474  | 60,526  | 38,183  | 27,956  | 44,404   | 55,596   | 22,328   | 35,389   | 13,061   | 18,621   | 54,074   | 45,926   | 54,8     | 26,741   |
| 23/04/24 | key1 23 | key2 23 | 34,42   | 24,273  | 11,412  | 4,024   | 37,892  | 83,097  | 16,903  | 5,491   | 25,096  | 52,904   | 47,096   | 12,596   | 16,247   | 3,65     | 9,031    | 61,866   | 38,134   | 26,245   | 31,466   |
| 24/04/24 | key1 24 | key2 24 | 19,595  | 25,241  | 21,675  | 13,96   | 24,744  | 52,442  | 47,558  | 25,883  | 46,902  | 48,926   | 51,074   | 20,159   | 30,142   | 9,983    | 16,989   | 55,501   | 44,499   | 30,356   | 46,583   |
| 25/04/24 | key1 25 | key2 25 | 9,458   | 17,28   | 21,049  | 19,229  | 19,906  | 29,326  | 70,674  | 49,625  | 57,795  | 45,129   | 54,871   | 27,054   | 60,605   | 33,552   | 32,809   | 50,118   | 49,882   | 27,902   | 70,77    |
| 26/04/24 | key1 26 | key2 26 | 16,968  | 23,801  | 22,257  | 15,61   | 18,808  | 46,818  | 53,182  | 30,926  | 40,503  | 47,339   | 52,661   | 15,219   | 20,545   | 5,326    | 8,717    | 59,318   | 40,682   | 16,316   | 46,254   |
| 27/04/24 | key1 27 | key2 27 | 34,546  | 24,143  | 11,249  | 3,931   | 38,274  | 83,404  | 16,596  | 5,347   | 25,067  | 52,987   | 47,013   | 9,872    | 12,181   | 2,309    | 6,503    | 65,067   | 34,933   | 20,907   | 29,079   |
| 28/04/24 | key1 28 | key2 28 | 28,628  | 26,973  | 16,943  | 7,982   | 31,372  | 70,793  | 29,207  | 12,265  | 35,669  | 50,845   | 49,155   | 9,974    | 12,327   | 2,353    | 6,796    | 64,934   | 35,066   | 25,193   | 25,252   |
| 29/04/24 | key1 29 | key2 29 | 23,009  | 26,505  | 20,355  | 11,724  | 28,14   | 59,501  | 40,499  | 20,144  | 45,104  | 49,812   | 50,188   | 18,542   | 26,722   | 8,18     | 15,342   | 56,644   | 43,356   | 31,738   | 41,387   |
| 30/04/24 | key1 30 | key2 30 | 25,858  | 27,015  | 18,815  | 9,828   | 30,007  | 65,249  | 34,751  | 15,936  | 41,117  | 50,332   | 49,668   | 9,611    | 11,809   | 2,198    | 6,404    | 65,413   | 34,587   | 27,362   | 21,952   |
| 01/05/24 | key1 31 | key2 31 | 26,958  | 27,067  | 18,117  | 9,095   | 30,394  | 67,45   | 32,55   | 14,433  | 38,784  | 50,511   | 49,489   | 22,379   | 35,526   | 13,147   | 16,629   | 54,024   | 45,976   | 58,469   | 21,862   |
| 02/05/24 | key1 32 | key2 32 | 15,441  | 22,775  | 22,395  | 16,516  | 23,552  | 43,451  | 56,549  | 34,155  | 53,707  | 48,043   | 51,957   | 23,244   | 37,941   | 14,697   | 21,005   | 53,511   | 46,489   | 54,677   | 29,892   |
| 03/05/24 | key1 33 | key2 33 | 17,013  | 23,829  | 22,25   | 15,582  | 23,994  | 46,916  | 53,084  | 30,833  | 51,227  | 48,409   | 51,591   | 24,547   | 42,126   | 17,579   | 18,622   | 52,635   | 47,365   | 20,426   | 64,747   |
| 04/05/24 | key1 34 | key2 34 | 16,192  | 23,297  | 22,347  | 16,076  | 24,232  | 45,116  | 54,884  | 32,538  | 53,425  | 48,327   | 51,673   | 21,467   | 33,195   | 11,728   | 19,398   | 54,641   | 45,359   | 34,084   | 46,6     |
| 05/05/24 | key1 35 | key2 35 | 31,522  | 26,215  | 14,534  | 6,043   | 34,324  | 76,689  | 23,311  | 8,777   | 31,307  | 51,638   | 48,362   | 15,658   | 21,309   | 5,651    | 3,404    | 58,922   | 41,078   | 54,691   | 5,064    |
| 06/05/24 | key1 36 | key2 36 | 16,255  | 23,34   | 22,341  | 16,039  | 23,296  | 45,256  | 54,744  | 32,403  | 51,509  | 48,133   | 51,867   | 26,666   | 52,681   | 26,015   | 31,576   | 51,192   | 48,808   | 35,653   | 61,254   |
| 07/05/24 | key1 37 | key2 37 | 18,826  | 24,861  | 21,887  | 14,452  | 22,298  | 50,815  | 49,185  | 27,298  | 43,805  | 48,392   | 51,608   | 25,45    | 45,671   | 20,221   | 28,296   | 52,166   | 47,834   | 52,003   | 40,794   |
| 08/05/24 | key1 38 | key2 38 | 11,686  | 19,622  | 21,964  | 18,44   | 22,749  | 34,787  | 65,213  | 43,249  | 59,41   | 46,951   | 53,049   | 14,413   | 19,179   | 4,765    | 10,399   | 60,058   | 39,942   | 37,313   | 24,948   |
| 09/05/24 | key1 39 | key2 39 | 23,419  | 26,61   | 20,157  | 11,452  | 28,491  | 60,334  | 39,666  | 19,509  | 44,72   | 49,898   | 50,102   | 15,32    | 20,72    | 5,4      | 11,828   | 59,235   | 40,765   | 31,172   | 33,815   |
| 10/05/24 | key1 40 | key2 40 | 30,673  | 26,529  | 15,296  | 6,615   | 33,623  | 74,935  | 25,065  | 9,769   | 33,065  | 51,388   | 48,612   | 14,833   | 19,884   | 5,052    | 10,241   | 59,669   | 40,331   | 22,373   | 40,562   |
| 11/05/24 | key1 41 | key2 41 | 24,039  | 26,749  | 19,843  | 11,04   | 28,021  | 61,589  | 38,411  | 18,568  | 42,3    | 49,916   | 50,084   | 16,156   | 22,192   | 6,036    | 10,894   | 58,51    | 41,49    | 21,117   | 44,722   |
| 12/05/24 | key1 42 | key2 42 | 13,314  | 21,104  | 22,3    | 17,674  | 23,451  | 38,617  | 61,383  | 39,082  | 57,728  | 47,581   | 52,419   | 26,827   | 54,229   | 27,401   | 33,749   | 51,044   | 48,956   | 39,35    | 59,259   |
| 13/05/24 | key1 43 | key2 43 | 26,722  | 27,063  | 18,272  | 9,252   | 30,263  | 66,978  | 33,022  | 14,75   | 39,212  | 50,468   | 49,532   | 9,636    | 11,845   | 2,209    | 6,42     | 65,379   | 34,621   | 21,916   | 27,469   |
| 14/05/24 | key1 44 | key2 44 | 19,126  | 25,013  | 21,808  | 14,26   | 24,929  | 51,452  | 48,548  | 26,74   | 48,33   | 48,893   | 51,107   | 23,207   | 37,831   | 14,624   | 15,868   | 53,483   | 46,517   | 18,695   | 62,525   |
| 15/05/24 | key1 45 | key2 45 | 20,034  | 25,442  | 21,539  | 13,676  | 24,838  | 53,364  | 46,636  | 25,097  | 46,065  | 49,001   | 50,999   | 16,1     | 22,092   | 5,992    | 12,444   | 58,562   | 41,438   | 37,874   | 28,969   |
| 16/05/24 | key1 46 | key2 46 | 23,135  | 26,538  | 20,295  | 11,64   | 25,658  | 59,757  | 40,243  | 19,948  | 40,135  | 49,534   | 50,466   | 14,381   | 19,125   | 4,744    | 8,888    | 60,085   | 39,915   | 42,762   | 18,341   |
| 17/05/24 | key1 47 | key2 47 | 15,658  | 22,929  | 22,385  | 16,39   | 24,441  | 43,934  | 56,066  | 33,681  | 54,921  | 48,285   | 51,715   | 20,88    | 31,788   | 10,908   | 17,36    | 55,014   | 44,986   | 28,365   | 50,001   |
| 18/05/24 | key1 48 | key2 48 | 22,223  | 26,275  | 20,711  | 12,244  | 26,827  | 57,895  | 42,105  | 21,394  | 44,621  | 49,56    | 50,44    | 24,579   | 42,242   | 17,663   | 23,917   | 52,686   | 47,314   | 56,975   | 31,599   |
| 19/05/24 | key1 49 | key2 49 | 9,237   | 17,027  | 20,925  | 19,285  | 19,449  | 28,771  | 71,229  | 50,305  | 57,258  | 44,848   | 55,152   | 23,574   | 38,927   | 15,353   | 17,992   | 53,266   | 46,734   | 21,708   | 61,454   |
| 20/05/24 | key1 50 | key2 50 | 24,813  | 26,888  | 19,425  | 10,525  | 23,068  | 63,151  | 36,849  | 17,425  | 30,48   | 49,539   | 50,461   | 15,211   | 20,532   | 5,32     | 9,224    | 59,325   | 40,675   | 45,127   | 17,789   |



and here's a markdown of Sheet2:


| % data1 |         | 34,2622 |  | % data5 |         | 37,3642 |  | % data9  |         | 58,8914 |  | % data13 |         | 62,3926 |  | % data17 |         | 50,0976 |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |  | ------- | ------- | ------- |  | -------- | ------- | ------- |  | -------- | ------- | ------- |  | -------- | ------- | ------- |
| key1 8  | key2 8  | 36,403  |  | key1 8  | key2 8  | 42,708  |  | key1 13  | key2 13 | 61,528  |  | key1 13  | key2 13 | 76,651  |  | key1 13  | key2 13 | 51,392  |
| key1 27 | key2 27 | 34,546  |  | key1 27 | key2 27 | 38,274  |  | key1 38  | key2 38 | 59,41   |  | key1 3   | key2 3  | 61,294  |  | key1 5   | key2 5  | 49,99   |
| key1 16 | key2 16 | 34,42   |  | key1 23 | key2 23 | 37,892  |  | key1 15  | key2 15 | 57,996  |  | key1 25  | key2 25 | 60,605  |  | key1 25  | key2 25 | 49,882  |
| key1 23 | key2 23 | 34,42   |  | key1 35 | key2 35 | 34,324  |  | key1 25  | key2 25 | 57,795  |  | key1 5   | key2 5  | 57,254  |  | key1 3   | key2 3  | 49,697  |
| key1 35 | key2 35 | 31,522  |  | key1 40 | key2 40 | 33,623  |  | key1 42  | key2 42 | 57,728  |  | key1 11  | key2 11 | 56,159  |  | key1 11  | key2 11 | 49,527  |
|         |         |         |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
|         |         |         |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
|         |         |         |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
| % data2 |         | 27,0324 |  | % data6 |         | 81,4186 |  | % data10 |         | 52,776  |  | % data14 |         | 35,9892 |  | % data18 |         | 67,458  |
| key1 31 | key2 31 | 27,067  |  | key1 8  | key2 8  | 88,968  |  | key1 8   | key2 8  | 54,963  |  | key1 13  | key2 13 | 52,718  |  | key1 5   | key2 5  | 79,902  |
| key1 43 | key2 43 | 27,063  |  | key1 27 | key2 27 | 83,404  |  | key1 27  | key2 27 | 52,987  |  | key1 3   | key2 3  | 34,26   |  | key1 11  | key2 11 | 73,907  |
| key1 20 | key2 20 | 27,039  |  | key1 23 | key2 23 | 83,097  |  | key1 23  | key2 23 | 52,904  |  | key1 25  | key2 25 | 33,552  |  | key1 3   | key2 3  | 61,672  |
| key1 30 | key2 30 | 27,015  |  | key1 35 | key2 35 | 76,689  |  | key1 35  | key2 35 | 51,638  |  | key1 5   | key2 5  | 30,229  |  | key1 21  | key2 21 | 60,943  |
| key1 5  | key2 5  | 26,978  |  | key1 40 | key2 40 | 74,935  |  | key1 40  | key2 40 | 51,388  |  | key1 11  | key2 11 | 29,187  |  | key1 19  | key2 19 | 60,866  |
| key1 9  | key2 9  | 26,978  |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
|         |         |         |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
|         |         |         |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
| % data3 |         | 22,3934 |  | % data7 |         | 75,8092 |  | % data11 |         | 57,8672 |  | % data15 |         | 37,9646 |  | % data19 |         | 66,4476 |
| key1 11 | key2 11 | 22,404  |  | key1 5  | key2 5  | 80,163  |  | key1 5   | key2 5  | 63,961  |  | key1 13  | key2 13 | 52,47   |  | key1 25  | key2 25 | 70,77   |
| key1 16 | key2 16 | 22,402  |  | key1 15 | key2 15 | 78,595  |  | key1 15  | key2 15 | 57,704  |  | key1 3   | key2 3  | 39,219  |  | key1 1   | key2 1  | 67,286  |
| key1 32 | key2 32 | 22,395  |  | key1 13 | key2 13 | 78,385  |  | key1 13  | key2 13 | 56,731  |  | key1 42  | key2 42 | 33,749  |  | key1 17  | key2 17 | 65,223  |
| key1 47 | key2 47 | 22,385  |  | key1 49 | key2 49 | 71,229  |  | key1 22  | key2 22 | 55,596  |  | key1 25  | key2 25 | 32,809  |  | key1 33  | key2 33 | 64,747  |
| key1 18 | key2 18 | 22,381  |  | key1 25 | key2 25 | 70,674  |  | key1 12  | key2 12 | 55,344  |  | key1 36  | key2 36 | 31,576  |  | key1 12  | key2 12 | 64,212  |
|         |         |         |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
|         |         |         |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
|         |         |         |  |         |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |  |          |         |         |
| % data4 |         | 19,3598 |  | % data8 |         | 56,3266 |  | % data12 |         | 26,9824 |  | % data16 |         | 65,7494 |  |          |         |         |
| key1 13 | key2 13 | 19,479  |  | key1 5  | key2 5  | 62,14   |  | key1 25  | key2 25 | 27,054  |  | key1 8   | key2 8  | 66,731  |  |          |         |         |
| key1 15 | key2 15 | 19,467  |  | key1 15 | key2 15 | 59,927  |  | key1 3   | key2 3  | 27,034  |  | key1 14  | key2 14 | 66,157  |  |          |         |         |
| key1 5  | key2 5  | 19,339  |  | key1 13 | key2 13 | 59,636  |  | key1 5   | key2 5  | 27,025  |  | key1 30  | key2 30 | 65,413  |  |          |         |         |
| key1 49 | key2 49 | 19,285  |  | key1 49 | key2 49 | 50,305  |  | key1 11  | key2 11 | 26,972  |  | key1 43  | key2 43 | 65,379  |  |          |         |         |
| key1 25 | key2 25 | 19,229  |  | key1 25 | key2 25 | 49,625  |  | key1 42  | key2 42 | 26,827  |  | key1 27  | key2 27 | 65,067  |  |          |         |         |




You could use a combination of VSTACK and HSTACK; could you give us some more data (mockup or limited data), so we can recreate the file, preferably with TableMarkdown.

You could place the the blocks horizontally (each block in one column) - then there is enough space downwards

sample data added
